# Deploy R app in shinyapps.io - Error: HTTP 404

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, shinyapps

When i try to publish R app in shinyapps.io , it shows an error:

```
Preparing to deploy application...Error: HTTP 404
GET https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/461629
Not Found
Execution halted
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you delete your app before you tried to publish it?

Comment: Yes, I've deleted.Actually it has 2 R app scripts, one is created for english and another one is created for german. so I've deleted the german app.

Comment: Can you clear the folder `rsconnect/shinyapps.io` in your app directory and try again?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably deleted the app before you tried to publish it. In this case clearing the contents of the folder named `rsconnect/shinyapps.io` will solve the issue.